# Can't mount EBS volumes (shown as NVME) in c5 AWS EC2 instance

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, mounted-volumes, nvme

People seem to have alot of issues with the newer instance type NVME volumes because of name mappings. That I can handle. For me, the issue is simple and worse: mounting doesn't have an effect:

```
ubuntu@ip-10-0-0-60:~$ lsblk
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
nvme0n1     259:2    0  48G  0 disk 
└─nvme0n1p1 259:3    0  48G  0 part /
nvme1n1     259:1    0  50G  0 disk 
nvme2n1     259:0    0  75G  0 disk 

ubuntu@ip-10-0-0-60:~$ sudo file -s /dev/nvme1n1
/dev/nvme1n1: Linux rev 1.0 ext4 filesystem data, UUID=7d277227-321c-4d52-9f7f-883f242dfdc7 (extents) (large files) (huge files)

ubuntu@ip-10-0-0-60:~$ df -h /data
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/nvme0n1p1   47G   18G   30G  38% /

ubuntu@ip-10-0-0-60:~$ sudo mount /dev/nvme1n1 /data

ubuntu@ip-10-0-0-60:~$ lsblk
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
nvme0n1     259:2    0  48G  0 disk 
└─nvme0n1p1 259:3    0  48G  0 part /
nvme1n1     259:1    0  50G  0 disk 
nvme2n1     259:0    0  75G  0 disk 

ubuntu@ip-10-0-0-60:~$ df -h /data
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/nvme0n1p1   47G   18G   30G  38% /
```

Any advice?

Comment: same here...I'm running into the same issue